# How do I prevent htaccess from triggering twice on redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following problem. My website "www.mysite.com" is currently protected by a htaccess password. So when I visit "www.mysite.com" a window pops up and I fill in my password.
However, after that I get redirected to "mysite.com" (without the "www") and I get asked to type in the password again.

This is my current htaccess file:

```
AuthName "My Site"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile w123456/mysite.com/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Just a normal password request. It's in the same directory of the index.php. The whole thing is a wordpress installation.
Maybe I need to add something, so it doesn't trigger twice?

Comment: `require user your_user_valid_one` for example `require user matt` and define matt:password into your authFile.

Comment: Make sure your site is setup for either www or non www in WP. Also use a rewriterule to enforce one or the other. So it should redirect first then prompt for password. Mine is setup similarly while doing dev work.

Comment: If this is WordPress then don't you have additional directives in `.htaccess`?